# Overlay watermark PNG on JPG file centered

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have a method that takes an image and resizes it and saves it preserving the exif information.  What I want to do now is overlay a transparent PNG image on top of the image as a watermark.  The size of the png will always be larger than any of the images I want to place it on.  I would like to center it on top of the image preserving the watermark's aspect ratio. Here is the code as I have it so far:

```
private static void ResizeImage(Image theImage, int newSize, string savePath, IEnumerable<PropertyItem> propertyItems)
{
    int width;
    int height;
    CalculateNewRatio(theImage.Width, theImage.Height, newSize, out width, out height);
    using (var b = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            using(var a = Image.FromFile("Watermark.png"))
            {
                g.DrawImage();  //What to do here?
            }
            g.DrawImage(theImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

            var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 80L);
            var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            var jpegCodec = codecs.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MimeType == "image/jpeg");
            var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            foreach(var item in propertyItems)
            {
                b.SetPropertyItem(item);
            }
            b.Save(savePath, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution, the code is below. May not be the optimal code but it is fast and does what I need it to do which is take all JPG images in a directory and re-size them to full and thumb images for a photo gallery while overlaying a watermark on the image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ImageResize
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        private static void Main()
        {
            var strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg");

            //Using parallel processing for performance
            Parallel.ForEach(strFiles, strFile =>
                                           {
                                               using (var image = Image.FromFile(strFile, true))
                                               {
                                                   var exif = image.PropertyItems;
                                                   var b = directory + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFile);
                                                   ResizeImage(image, 800, b + "_FULL.jpg", exif);
                                                   ResizeImage(image, 200, b + "_THUMB.jpg", exif);
                                               }
                                               File.Delete(strFile);
                                           });
        }

        private static void ResizeImage(Image theImage, int newSize, string savePath, IEnumerable<PropertyItem> propertyItems)
        {
            try
            {
                int width;
                int height;
                CalculateNewRatio(theImage.Width, theImage.Height, newSize, out width, out height);
                using (var b = new Bitmap(width, height))
                {
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
                    {
                        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        g.DrawImage(theImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

                        //Using FileStream to avoid lock issues because of the parallel processing
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(directory + "\\Watermark.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            using (var overLay = Image.FromStream(stream))
                            {
                                stream.Close();
                                int newWidth;
                                int newHeight;
                                CalculateNewRatio(overLay.Width, overLay.Height, height > width ? width : newSize, out newWidth, out newHeight);
                                var x = (b.Width - newWidth) / 2;
                                var y = (b.Height - newHeight) / 2;
                                g.DrawImage(overLay, new Rectangle(x, y, newWidth, newHeight));
                            }
                        }

                        var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 80L);
                        var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                        var jpegCodec = codecs.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MimeType == "image/jpeg");
                        var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
                        foreach (var item in propertyItems)
                        {
                            b.SetPropertyItem(item);
                        }
                        b.Save(savePath, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void CalculateNewRatio(int width, int height, int desiredSize, out int newWidth, out int newHeight)
        {
            if ((width >= height && width > desiredSize) || (width <= height && height > desiredSize))
            {
                if (width > height)
                {
                    newWidth = desiredSize;
                    newHeight = height*newWidth/width;
                }
                else if (width < height)
                {
                    newHeight = desiredSize;
                    newWidth = width*newHeight/height;
                }
                else
                {
                    newWidth = desiredSize;
                    newHeight = desiredSize;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = width;
                newHeight = height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To scale an image onto a canvas for the best fit while preserving the aspect ratio, the process is fairly simple:

```
double widthFactor = b.Width / a.Width;
double heightFactor = b.Height / a.Height;
double scaleFactor = Math.Min(widthFactor, heightFactor);
int newWidth = a.Width * scaleFactor;
int newHeight = a.Width * scaleFactor;
```

To calculate the position to center the image just requires a little more math:

```
int left = (b.Width - newWidth) / 2;
int top = (b.Height - newHeight) / 2;
```

Then use the appropriate form of the Graphics.DrawImage method.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to resize an image, I am looking for how to center the resized image over another image. My CalculateNewRatio method (not included) does something very similar to this.

Comment: Since you've already got positioning and size covered, what portions of the problem do you still need assistance with? Is it handling the transparency of the watermark that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I figured it out and will post the solution.  int newWidth and int newHeight throw a compile time error because of the conversion of double to int.  Even after fixing that, using your formula the image was still crushed a little thus not preserving it's aspect ratio.